# Error in installing SimpleDB::Class

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I try to install SimpleDB::Class from cpan as sudo cpan SimpleDB::Class. it needs a dependency  Memcached::libmemcached. so i try to install it, but it have the following errors.

```
CCLD   clients/memstat
CC     tests/atomsmasher.o
CCLD   tests/atomsmasher
CXX    tests/tests_hashplus-hash_plus.o
./config/depcomp: line 611: exec: g++: not found
make[2]: *** [tests/tests_hashplus-hash_plus.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vanitha/.cpan/build/Memcached-libmemcached-0.4406-    Oq4Z_m/src/libmemcached'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vanitha/.cpan/build/Memcached-libmemcached-0.4406-  Oq4Z_m/src/libmemcached'
make: *** [install] Error 2
Unable to build libmemcached: Error running cd src/libmemcached && make install

Aborted.
No 'Makefile' created  TIMB/Memcached-libmemcached-0.4406.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
Make had some problems, won't install
could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec: g++: not found` - this is the error

Try this first of all: `sudo apt-get install g++`